# Oauth2 sincronización de tarea cron

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cron, oauth2

tengo desarrollada una integración con una API a través de oauth2. Lo tengo desarrollado en php. Tiene un inconveniente y es que para sincronizar los datos, tengo que entrar en esa pagina de php y esperar a que haga esa redirección para poder obtener el token. Pues bien, me gustaría automatizar esto con una tarea cron llamandolo desde el servidor un archivo php que llame a las funciones.

Mi principal problema viene con el code, este es necesario para la consulta del token. El code se resetea en el servidor cada 10 minutos. La consulta del code va antes que la del token, y esta consulta en su respuesta realiza como una redirección. Mi duda en el fondo es, ¿Esto es posible sin redirecciones a través de ajax por ejemplo? o es una limitación de la API. ¿Hay alguna forma automatizar esto? ¿Todo es propio de oauth2 o del desarrollo de la API?

```
function getToken(){

 $clientId = 'd3ca6f1b873035168';
 $clientSecret = '56b4a5d6f64d';

$redirectUri = 'https://www.prueba.com:443/cron-pruebas.php';

if (!empty($_GET['code'])) {

  $code = rawurldecode($_GET['code']);

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://app.prueba.eu/oauth2/access_token');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
      'code' => $code,
      'client_id' => $clientId,
      'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
      'redirect_uri' => "$redirectUri",
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
  ]);

  $response = curl_exec($ch);
  $data = json_decode($response, true);
  $accessToken = $data['access_token'];
  error_log("El token!!!");
  error_log("\r\n".$accessToken,3,"token.log");

  } else {

  $query = [
      'client_id' => $clientId,
      'response_type' => 'code',
      'redirect_uri' => "$redirectUri",
  ];

  header('Location: https://app.prueba.eu/oauth2/authorize?' . 
  http_build_query($query));

   }

   }
```

Comment: ¿El proveedor del API te permite generar claves de aplicación? Son las que necesitas para autenticar tu aplicación cron contra el servicio.

Comment: Sin código no se puede ayudar mucho

Comment: @OscarGarcia desde la api me facilitan el clientid y el client secret. Pero a parte antes de solicitar el token , tengo que hacer otra consulta que me devuelve un code. Este code lo tengo que poner después en la consulta del token. Con la clave te refieres a esto?. A parte en la documentación especifica que este code caduca cada 10 minutos.

Comment: @FernandoTorres he añadido el código. Esto sería el ejemplo que me da la api. Pero yo no quiero realizar esa redirección. Para ello había pensado hacerlo con ajax, pero volvemos al tema , ¿Esto es posible?

Comment: El tipo de autenticación que intentas hacer es de usuario, en el que éste tiene iniciada la sesión en el proveedor y tu aplicación le redirige allí para generar un testigo que es devuelto en la llamada de vuelta. Eso es complicado de desarrollar en un script que línea de comandos en el que tendrías que similar la autenticación de usuario en el proveedor, por lo que existen otros métodos de autenticación a través de claves de aplicación.

Comment: Como sabrás, OAuth permite delegar permisos de un usuario a una aplicación, pero para comunicación servidor-servidor se suelen usar otros métodos y ese método en particular depende del proveedor de servicios de API que uses. Ejemplo en el API de Google: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/service-account.php Si nos dices qué servicio quieres consumir podremos consultar la documentación para indicarte la mejor forma de hacer uso de su API de la forma que deseas hacerlo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Esta url corresponde a la documentación de la API https://developer.teamleader.eu/

Comment: Lo siento @sourcer, pero esa API parece que únicamente permite crear integraciones en el navegador de manera interactiva, de modo que el usuario debe aceptar el acceso a sus datos desde tu aplicación. Parece que lo más sencillo que podrías hacer es desarrollar ese trabajo haciendo uso de automatismos como te ofrece [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/tutorials/helloworld/helloworld.htm) que requiere sesión real de usuario o, mejor aún, [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial) que puede funcionar en modo no visible (headless).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Gracias por la ayuda!